# How to query for a week using key => value WP_Query argument notation?

Tags: wp-query, query

I would like to be able to query for a specific year and week using WP_Query argument notation. I am using this notation as I would like the page to paginate.

What's the correct "year" and "week" key value notation for performing the query in this manner?

I know I could do something like this, but I would like the page to paginate.

Here's the bit of code I'm using for the key-value wp_query notation:

```
<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('category_name' => 'whats-happening', 'year' => 2012, 'week' => 46 ,'paged' => $paged);
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); }
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
?>

HTML post structure to loop through....

<?php if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) : ?>
    <?php next_posts_link( __('<span class="older">&larr; Older</span>') ); ?>
    <?php previous_posts_link( __('<span class="newer">Newer &rarr;</span>') ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
    if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')){ wp_pagenavi(); }
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = $temp;
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: While your Question is beyond my scope, I thought I'd comment on the first line: `$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;`. You're unnecessarily running the function `get_query_var` twice. Better would be: `$paged = get_query_var('paged'); if ( ! $paged ) $paged = 1;`.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a `week` query variable, but there is `w`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Time_Parameters

> w (int) - Week of the year (from 0 to 53). Uses the MySQL WEEK command. The mode is dependent on the "start_of_week" option.

Your args should look like this:

```
$args = array('category_name' => 'whats-happening', 'year' => 2012, 'w' => 46 ,'paged' => $paged);
```

Comment: this does in fact work; however, my pagination fails to show up at the bottom of the page with this query. Any idea would this could be?

Comment: You mean the numbered page links on the bottom of the page?

Comment: The next_posts_link() and previous_posts_link() aren't showing. I'm guessing this is because I am only querying for a specific year and week value? I thought I would be able to to see an "Older" and "Newer" pagination link.

Comment: Are there enough posts for those links to show up?

Comment: yes, there are enough posts.